# My Controller not posting, error Missing required parameters: id

Tags: javascript

I have modified my controller [Bookscontroller] so that it checks the book's id so that the same book is not borrowed twice but it can't now post to the database. enter image description here $model = new Books();
 $model = new Books();

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if(Books::findOne($model->book_id))


        {
         Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger','The book is not available.You can borrow another book another book.');
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'book_id' => $model->book_id]);
    }


    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I have some question if you are using if(Books::findOne($model->book_id))
for the availability of book that can be false cuz, it will return a flash message
for all the book and will appear not available so the solution is to to the condition
on the status, if(Books::findOne($model->status)) and that means that if status equal to 1 then it will appear that the book is not available cuz it's been borrowed by someone 
and for posting to the database you are not using any model->save so the model->load
is only for submitting the button but not for the save or the update